# Existence of a function,$f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm totally lost at this problem. Could anyone advise on the approach to it?

Suppose $H: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is a function. For each $m\in \mathbb{N},$ define a function $h_{m}: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ as follows: $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} [h_{m}(n)=H(m,n)]$. Prove there is a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ such that for each $m\in \mathbb{N},\left\{n\in \mathbb{N}: f(n) = h_{m}(n)\right\}$ is an infinite set.

Comment: Hint: $1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f\left(2^{k-1}(2l-1)\right):=h_k\left(2^{k-1}(2l-1)\right)$ for $k, l \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** diagonalisation.

You'll probably want $f(0)=h_0(0)$ and then $f(1)=h_1(1)$ and $f(2)=h_0(2)$. Can you extend this using a diagonalisation argument? Can you then also show that $\{n \mid f(n)=h_m(n)\}$ is an infinite set?